# I wound like to fix Horizontal UIPickerView code in ios

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I found Horizontal UIPickerView . but this code is not working .

(//this: )is error area.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic)UIPickerView * myPickerView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *pickerViewArray;

 #import "ViewController.h"

 @implementation ViewController

@synthesize myPickerView;
@synthesize pickerViewArray;

-(void)loadView{
// Write code to create self.view
// Then...
pickerViewArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    @"John Appleseed", @"Chris Armstrong", @"Serena Auroux",
                    @"Susan Bean", @"Luis Becerra", @"Kate Bell", @"Alain Briere",
                    nil] copy];
myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; //this:thread1 error
myPickerView.delegate = self;
     //this: Passing "ViewController 'const_strong'to parameter of incompatible      
    //type'id<UIPickerViewDelegate>   

                        .
                        .
                        . 
   }
```

I would like to fix error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
self.myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 215)];
```